# What causes monitors to turn fully green while 'Netflixing'?

Tags: windows-7, gpu, netflix

I noticed that when I watch Netflix and turn off all monitors but the one I'm using to watch and turn them back on, they turn solid green, or just are black. I can fix this by restarting or unplugging from the GPU and plugging back in. This sometimes happens when not watching Netflix too, but very rarely.

This is on my R9 290 with triple monitors on Windows 7 and Chrome. I recently thought this was a problem with AMD, but my 970 friend with two monitors said he occasionally has the same issue. Watching Netflix at times when it happens too.

Comment: Hi - i have seen this happening from time to time, and have been able to resolve it by switching to software rendering rather than gpu rendering within the browser. In IE, you do this through Tools > Internet Options > Advanced...

Comment: @JimNielsen How about Chrome?

Comment: Settings > Show advanced settings > System - untick "Use hardware acceleration..."

Comment: Tried that, monitors turned green again when turning back on while watching Netflix.

Comment: I am assuming you have updated your graphics drivers to latest available version and have updated to the latest version of Microsoft Silverlight. Does this happen on other sites as well f.ex watching youtube videos..? Does issue manifest itself in both IE and Chrome..?

Comment: Haven't tried anything other than Netflix and Chrome. Don't have Silverlight installed. Latest graphics card drivers are installed though.

Comment: Firstly -Do you by chance have KB2670838 installed..? If yes, uninstall, reboot and recheck if netflix and chrome combination is working.

Comment: Secondly - when a video is playing right click on the video, select settings, and uncheck the hardware acceleration option

Comment: When I get home, I'll definitely try that. I also noticed that there's an update for one of my monitors... Getting that